# Woocommerce add the user email to new order notification recipients

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, email-notifications

I am trying to add the user contact email as a recipient to the new order confirmation email. By default, WooCommerce sends the New Order email notification to the customer billing email address and not to the contact information email address.

The reason why is that we use WooCommerce to handle our online sales, but we also use for our offline sale. We have retailers that resell our products and once they send us a purchase order that we manually add to a new order with the items they want.

The issue we are facing is that the person responsible of the purchase (contact information email) wants to receive a confirmation email as well as the accounting department (billing email address).

I added this code to my function.php file:

```php
function add_additional_email_recipient( $recipient, $order ) {
    // Get the user email from the order
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $user = $order->get_user();
    $user_id = $order->get_user_id();
    $user_email = get_userdata( $user_id )->user_email;
    
    // Add the user email to the recipient list
    if ( ! empty( $user_email ) ) {
        $recipient .= ',' . $user_email;
    }
    
    return $recipient;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'add_additional_email_recipient', 10, 2 );
```

Although, I am having this error when I create a manual order in the backend: There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.

Answer (score 0):

There is something missing from your code to avoid an error in the admin, and some mistakes.

Try the following revisited code:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'add_user_email_recipient_to_new_order', 10, 2 );
function add_user_email_recipient_to_new_order( $recipient, $order = false ) {
    if ( ! $order || ! is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) 
        return $recipient;

    // Get the WP_User object from the order
    $user = $order->get_user();

    // Get the user email
    $user_email = $user->user_email;
    
    // Add the user email to the recipients
    if ( ! empty( $user_email ) ) {
        $recipient .= ',' . $user_email;
    }
    return $recipient;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the  child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and work.

> Note that the New Order email notification is only sent to the admin. The New Order email content is different from the email notifications sent to the customer, that are based on the order status.

Comment: Crashed my website haha.

Comment: This seems to be sending admin new order notification email to the customer as well. I would like both emails to receive the customer new order confirmation. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Nop! That has nothing to do with the code… New order notification is sent to the admin when a new order is created **AND depending on the order status you set, an email notification is sent to the customer billing email**. This is how work WooCommerce orders notifications basically. **So this code is not sending an email notification to the customer  billing email** … As this answer works and answer your initial question, could you please accept this answer (To mark an answer as accepted,
 click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in), thank you.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec can you suggest a variation of this code to ALWAYS send billing_email an email of the order even for all statuses of order including "on_hold" and "processing". I tested and don't receive any notification to the billing_email when using bank transfer payment method or cash

Comment: @pablorenato This code works as it's. The customer billing email is always used by WooCommerce, to send an email notification when order has one of the following statuses: on-hold, processing, completed, refunded (also for customer-note and customer invoice too). **New Order email notification is for the admin** not for the customer billing email…